# curl command giving 'curl: (6) Could not resolve host: XXX.XXX.XXX' error on aws ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, curl, amazon-ec2

I am hitting a third party api using curl on aws ubuntu ec2 instance but it is giving me error as below -

```
#curl: (6) Could not resolve host: some.website.address#
```

Below is the command -

> curl -H "Authorization: Bearer 47977407fc6c82478e57709523767c62:112b8a226124afca5df3381b6612bb3b" https://some.website.address/v1/authentication

I have tried with single quotes, double quotes, removing space after **"Authorization:**    but nothing is working.

This scenario is only with AWS ec2 instance, on local machine i am getting proper response. Also I have checked 'some.website.address' is working well.

Need help!

Comment: did your instance able to talk outer world? try to  `ping google.com`. seems like instance is in private subnet without NAT

Comment: gave me this

ping: https://google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution

Comment: were you able to do that before? did you confirm that instance is not in private subnet?

Comment: if in public subnet then try to restart instance

Comment: @Adiii we were able to do this before. will check about public/private subnet

Comment: then restart it if you are able to do this before. Also check Security group out bound rule

Comment: @Adiii will try this.

Comment: I don't want to loose current IP, my IP is public. Can not restart!

Comment: oh then did you check outbound rule? also check `cat /etc/resolv.conf ` and try one more thing ssh or curl to other instance in same `vpc`

Comment: 646 Q/A here when you search for `curl could not resolve host`. Good luck.